# Should I buy a Gigabit switch or upgrade to Gigabit router for home streaming?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, nas

I have just purchased a WD My Cloud NAS which I am using directly plugged in to my TP-Link 841N 300Mbps router. I have tested the NAS by plugging it in directly to my Laptop's Ethernet port (Gigabit), and I am getting much higher transfer speeds than connection laptop via router (Wired). Although, the wireless connection is SIGNIFICANTLY slower, I conclude it's router that's bottleneck. I want to stream my stored Blu-Rays on TV and Laptop WIRELESSLY. The router is unable to transmit the files at those high bitrates. Hence, the question.

Addition: Should I need to upgrade to Gigabit router, do I need a dual-band or Tri-band router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your router is the bottleneck - however there are a couple of issues here.

The first is that the ethernet ports on the router max out at 100 megabit - Even if your WIFI is capable of doing 300 megabit (which its not in practice), the bottleneck will be 100 megabit.

What you need is a WIFI AP or router which has gigabit ports and, if you are insistent on using WIFI, can sustain speeds >= 1 gigabit.  While this is possible, its a bit of an ask - you are better off using ethernet cable on a gigabit switch where possible.

Whether you require a single, dual or tri-band router - and if it is even possible to get gigabit speeds depends on the environment the WIFI router is working in - as well as the abilities of the receiver.   It is unlikely you will get the performance you are seeking if the receiver does not have multiple antennas or is not 802.11ac capable.  It is unlikely that a LAPTOP will have tri-band, but it may very well have dual band if it is fairly new.

From a practical POV, provided your LAPTOP is capable of handling 802.11ac, you will get better performance - probably markedly better - from a new router.  A tri-band router will probably not perform much better then a dual band one in your case.  Your best bet, however, is to use ethernet for streaming connections.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to ask about opinions, but after reading your answer, I did some research. Is ASUS RT-AC87U a good choice? My TV does support 802.11ac and unfortunately my Asus K53SD laptop does not.

Comment: The Asus RT-AC87U has an excellent reputation for performance and reliability, and would be high up on my shortlist - although it's fairly pricy

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your help. A quick question: Is the Asus router able to establish a stable Connection up to 7 metres, so that I can stream 4K videos?

Comment: It depends on the environment (noise from other devices,  obstacles  etc)  and the bitrate of the video - but in a typical environment this should work fine (from the NAS to an 802.11ac device).  No one can give you guarantees without in-depth knowledge of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your actual router, is that it only have 100 Mbps ethernet ports, and no Gigabit one. The bottleneck come from here, and not your wifi.

Getting a new router with Gigabit ports on it will solve your problem. A dual band may be enough if you only have your TV and laptop on it. Also, make sure that the frenquencies match the ones supported by both of your devices !

Comment: I have 4-5 Cellphones and a BRAVIA Android TV, a laptop and an old Desktop connected via LAN to router. '

Comment: The TV is DLNA supported, and I am not sure how I can test if it supports the frequencies.

Comment: By "frequencies" I mean protocols. You can have a look at [this array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Protocol), comparing the differents wifi protocols. Most commons ones are b, g, n and ac